# T woocommerce featured products fails to adjust size of product container

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I used template that displays three featured products on home page. I want to display five of them (not three). I modified CSS to shrink width of featured product box but for some reason it fails to  display five featured products. Is there way to display 5 elements of featured products?

This is what I have now:

[image: What I have now]

And this is what I want to achieve:

[image: What I want to achieve]

this is CSS that I used to force width of featured products:

```
.product-block{
width: 166px !important;
}
```

EDIT 1:

I got template that display only 3 featured products (check image bellow)

[image: original position of featured products]

What I want to achieve is to display 5 featured products!
To do that I added this code that shrinked width of product box:

```
#featured-carousel > div.slider-wrapper-outer > div > li {
width: 186px !important;

}
```

After using this code I shrinked all products but from that point margins got bugged and slider transition was buggy

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.product-block img{max-width:100%;height:auto;}
```

What we are doing here is telling the image to get the full width of the container.

Comment: thank you for your answer. When I enter your code I got three featured products instead of five

Comment: are you using your css style? `producto-block{width:166px important!}`if not, please add to the styles

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.